# Random crash at app launch

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I build an weather app, that uses openweathermap API.
It's very simple, the app uses plist file to store a list of cities.  When the user launches the app, it will loop through the `cityNames` array, and retrieve the requested weather data.

My issue is, the app will crash randomly when launch.  It gives "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." at this line of code,

`let weather = Weather(labelCityName: cityName!, temp: temp!, icon: weatherIcon!)`

If this happens every time, I know there is a `nil` in the above variables.  But the problem is, with the same list of `cityNames`, without changing anything, I just click 'run' then 'stop', then 'run' again on Xcode.  The app can crash.

Here is how I save and load the plist file:

```
    // Save city list
func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as [String]
    return path[0]
}

func dataFilePath() -> String {
    return "\(documentsDirectory())/Checklists.plist"
}

func saveCityList() {
    let data = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: data)
    archiver.encodeObject(cityNames, forKey: "cityNames")
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    data.writeToFile(dataFilePath(), atomically: true)
}
    // Load city list
func loadCityList() {
    let path = dataFilePath()
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data)
        storedCityNames = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("cityNames") as! [String]
        unarchiver.finishDecoding()
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I use `print` command to print out each array, `cityNames`,`temp`,`weatherIcon`.  Here is what it looks like when it loop through some cities then crash:

`***Check***Optional("Albany"),Optional(272),Optional("04n")
***Check***nil,nil,nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is how I get the data using SwiftyJSON:

```
    func getWeather(city: String) {

    let cityEscaped = city.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

    let path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(cityEscaped!)&appid=d21991d7851f849bfe8cc24d12c795d0"
    let url = NSURL(string: path)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        let json = JSON(data: data!)
        let temp = json["main"]["temp"].int
        let weatherIcon = json["weather"][0]["icon"].string
        let cityName = json["name"].string

        print("***Check***\(cityName),\(temp),\(weatherIcon)")
        let weather = Weather(labelCityName: cityName!, temp: temp!, icon: weatherIcon!)

        if self.wServiceDelegate != nil {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.wServiceDelegate?.setWeather(weather)
            })
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: When it does crash, are you using the debugger to find out which variable contains nil?

Comment: @Michael I just update some information. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than implicitly unwrapping, conditionally unwrap the values and set a breakpoint if a value is nil, then work back through your code to determine why it is nil.  The code you have shown here doesn't show where the values are coming from.

Comment: Try using `let cityName = json["name"]?.string` and see if it works. Let me know what happens.

Comment: @TheRohanSanap This won't work, Xcode gives me "cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'JSON'". I also tried `let json = JSON(data: data?)` that erred too.